# Automate capturing photograph on ESP32-CAM

Tags: esp32

I want to capture photographs from the ESP32 camera, but not doing it manually. Specifically, when a signal is sent from a sensor, I want ESP32 to understand that, and start taking photographs **automatically** for some seconds. The main problem, is the automation. I have searched on the web a lot, but can't find any answers. I am not expecting answers with code -since this is difficult- rather than some sites that provide solution to my problem. Thank you.

Comment: What sensor are you using?

Comment: @PythonSchlange ultrasonic.

Comment: ping it with an esp8266 monitoring the sensor.

Comment: So what about using `if(distance <= distance_when_triggered) capture_photo();`. I'm not sure if you want to make multiple photos at once, but then you'd have to put `capture_photo();` into a for-loop. If this is what you were looking for, I'd suggest learning the basics of C/C++, which will make programming Arduino a lot easier.

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look https://github.com/Yurik72/ESPHap/tree/master/examples/ESPHAPCamera
The project has different things, but definetelly doing what you asked, captures photo by external event, command...

Comment: I'll take a look at it. Thanks!